# Refreshing page results in re-login?

Tags: jsp, shiro

I've configured shiro in the project to work for username/password validation.  'filters' and 'urls' are as below.

```
[filters]   
authc.loginUrl = /login.jsp 
shiro.loginUrl = /login.jsp 
[urls]   
/login.jsp = anon, authc 
/index.jsp = authc
```

Now anytime when we access index.jsp, it will redirect to login.jsp, even if I just refresh index.jsp.

How can I make it keep stay on index.jsp when I refresh index.jsp if cache still know that this user has already logged on?

By the way, I haven't configured cache manager so when started it would pop out the error like 'org.apache.shiro.realm.AuthorizingRealm - No cache or cacheManager properties have been set.  Authorization cache cannot be obtained.' Shall I configure as below (I only use shiro core & web)?

```
builtInCacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager 
securityManager.cacheManager = $builtInCacheManager
```

Answer (score 1):

Just starting shiro but this link should help: http://raibledesigns.com/rd/entry/java_web_application_security_part2 See the "conclusion" section. Most notably how authc, enforces authentication in the current session (which as far as I understand depends on the current thread invocation, probably using thread local), so you don't want authc but a specific role. Or user as in the example case because that means you are a know user... which is different than authenticated (a stronger statement).

Further if the distinction isn't clear: With shiro authenticated means that you just entered your user/pass, you know that must be the user. A remembered user has signed in but if the session has not expired, you are still logged in, you could leave and someone else could sit down. There are still cases, say a large payment or other secure operations (police or other sensitive information) where you may want to request credentials specifically for that service.